# StackUnderflow.js: A JavaScript Library and Mashup Application

Tags: app, library

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

StackUnderflow.js is a lightweight JavaScript library that makes retrieving and rendering question summary information from Stack Exchange sites simple. It supports retrieving questions by question ID, tags, keyword, and even by Google search results to enable you to search the body of questions, even though the Stack Exchange API does not support it.

StackUnderflow.js is designed to be used within your own sites, enabling you to easily include Stack Exchange information on your sites.

It also adds the ability to search the *content* of questions by abstracting away an Ajax Google search for you. This enables some powerful capabilities, such as:

- Display questions that link to your blog.
- Display questions that link to the current blog article.
- Display questions related to keyword or tags on a bug tracking site.
- Display questions related to a feature directly from online documentation for your products.

The screenshot above shows it in action, automatically displaying stackoverflow.com questions that link to my blog (and as you click on an article, each questions that link to each article). You can see that live by scrolling the bottom of my blog, http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop

#### License

Free to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, just include the the given license to give credit to the original.

#### Download

Download the library directly at http://github.com/InfinitiesLoop/StackUnderflow.js/downloads.
Or, link to it directly from your site: [http://infinity88.com/stackunderflow/stackunderflow-1.0.0.min.js](http://infinity88.com/stackunderflow/stackunderflow-1.0.3.min.js)
Or better yet, fork and customize StackUnderflow.js on GitHub, [StackUnderflow.js on GitHub](http://github.com/infinitiesloop/StackUnderflow.js).

Please read the README on the main GitHub page on how to get started.

#### Platform

JavaScript

### Contact

Created by Dave Reed (AKA InfinitiesLoop).
Blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop
Twitter: http://twitter.com/infinitiesloop
Twitter: http://twitter.com/StckUnderflowJS

### Code

The code is JavaScript -- please do feel free to contribute! The best way to do that is to fork the project on GitHub. You may also contact me directly via Twitter or the contact form on my blog, or here on Stack Apps.